# Symfony2 limit access user

Tags: php, symfony

I want to limit user access only for admin on some routers and I want to know how is it best practice to do that, is it possible from routing (example after call my function from controller I want to call one function who say `true` if I'm admin or `false` if not) or need for all function call my function first for verify.

I was read the documentation symfony2 but no specific noting if is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to limit access on specific routes, you can do so with Symfony's Access Control in your security.yml. Read the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#securing-specific-url-patterns) in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#book-security-securing-controller in the Symfony2 documentation. You need to access the security.context service and return the proper value based on the user's roles.